# Problems when using threads in IJava at Jupyter notebooks

Tags: java, jupyter-notebook, java-threads

I need to explain some concepts relating Threads and concurrency in Java, and I thought that using an IJava kernel in Jupyter notebooks would be a good approach to write the lecture notes.

But the very first code using threads in the notebook yield an incorrect result.
The code is the following:

```
Runnable r = () -> {
    for (int x = 1; x <6; x++) {
        System.out.println("Runnable running " + x);
    }
};
Thread t = new Thread(r);
t.start();
```

And the expected result is:

```
Runnable running 1
Runnable running 2
Runnable running 3
Runnable running 4
Runnable running 5
```

But what I obtain in the notebook is:
[image]

Not sure what happens here and why the rest of the x values are not printed.
As a comparison, I run the code in an IDE and it works as expected.

[image]

**Some idea of why it is not working?**

I also tried to add some `t.sleep(1000)` after the println but to no avail.

Is IJava a reliable kernel, since it has not been updated since 2019?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not in position to confirm this, but from what I can tell IJava is based on JShell rather than native Java.  What I think is happening is that JShell is peremptorily closing when your `main` method ends.  But the `main` method ends before the child thread has finished.  Try adding a `t.join()` call after `t.start()`.  That will cause `main` to pause until the child thread has terminated.

Note that this doesn't happen when using a native JVM.  The (normal) termination condition for a JVM is that all non-daemon threads have terminated.  Your child thread isn't a daemon thread so the JVM waits until it finishes ... after your main thread finishes.

> Is IJava a reliable kernel, since it has not been updated since 2019?

I have no idea.  Try finding and looking at the issue tracker for the project.

Comment: In JShell it works properly, so I guess is a problem with Jupyter and the way the cells work, as commented in other answer.

Comment: Ah.  OK.  As I said, I wasn't in a position to (investigate and) confirm the precise cause of the problem.  The solution is the same though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with a background thread writing io. To try and associate it with the correct cell, the io streams are tied to the currently executing cell. When nothing is in progress the output is dropped.

To rework your example a bit, one option is to just wait for the thread to finish executing:

```java
Runnable r = () -> {
    for (int x = 1; x <6; x++) {
        System.out.println("Runnable running " + x);
    }
};
Thread t = new Thread(r);
t.start();
t.join();
```

The above prints what you'd expect:

```
Runnable running 1
Runnable running 2
Runnable running 3
Runnable running 4
Runnable running 5
```

The way the jupyter architecture is structured, a kernel and frontend are separate. Logically there can even be multiple frontends sharing the same kernel so it isn't as straight forward to push background output from the kernel. Possible that IJava should just keep sending output to the last executed cell but I vaguely remember something along the lines of the spec not promising that frontends will continue accepting input from those streams after a cell is finished executing. (I think classic notebook does but colab doesn't for example).

So to sum things up, threads and background threads should work fine, the io is the issue. If you have other methods of seeing the behavior of that (changing a variable, writing to a file, etc. you should be able to observe that).

Comment: Yep, it seems to be a problem with Jupyter, since the same code works well on JShell. Thank you.

Comment: Now I wonder if Jupyter is the correct tool to teach thread-related code, since I am having issues with very simple snippets and I am not sure that future problems could be solved with a single "join"

Comment: I definitely see a lot of value in runnable lecture notes, kudos for putting in the effort towards that. Can't really speak about future problems, its possible they won't play nicely but also possible they just need some creative solutions :) That may depend on if you have some control over the frontend being used to view the notes.